# Should I avoid loops in joins?

Tags: sql, database, join, business-objects

I remember I was taught to **never create a loop** when joining tables in sql.
In effect, using Business Objects it even tells me if there are loops in the schema I've defined in the Universe.
I've tried to search on the web about this statement but I wasn't able to find a reference.
Why is it dangerous to do this?

***Edit: maybe I was too succint.***

My question wasn't about looping intended as a "FOR LOOP" or similar.
I was talking about something like this WHERE clause in a SELECT statement:

```
WHERE TABLE1.foo = TABLE2.foo
  AND TABLE2.bar = TABLE3.bar
  AND TABLE3.baz = TABLE1.baz
```

if you draw the relation you will see "a loop" in the join. 
Is this dangerous from a correctness and/or performance point of view?
Thanks to all.

***Edit 2: added an example.***

I've just thought an example, maybe it isn't the best, but I think it will serve to understand.

```
------------          -----------------      ----------------------
- DELIVERY -          - DELIVERY_DATE -      -  DELIVERY_DETAILS  -
------------          -----------------      ----------------------
- id       - <---     - id            - <----- date_id            -
- company  -     |----- delivery_id   -      - product            -
- year     -          - date          -      - quantity           -
- number   -          -----------------      - datetime_of_event  - 
- customer -                                 ----------------------
- ----------          

             1 <-----> N               1 <----> N
```

- In the DELIVERY table every delivery appears only once
- In the DELIVERY_TABLE we have the list of every date in which the delivery was processed. So, a delivery may be prepared in several days.
- In the last table we have the details of every delivery. So, in this table we track every event related to the preparation of the delivery

So, the cardinalities are 1:N for each couple of tables.

The join is very simple:

```
DELIVERY.id = DELIVERY_DATE.delivery_id AND 
DELIVERY_DATE.id = DELIVERY_DETAILS.date_id
```

Now, suppose I want to join another table, where I have some other information for a delivery in a certain date.
Let's define it:

```
------------  
- EMPLOYEE -
------------
- company  -
- year     -
- number   -
- date     -
- employee -
------------
```

Now the join should be:

```
DELIVERY.id = DELIVERY_DATE.delivery_id AND 
EMPLOYEE.company = DELIVERY.company AND
EMPLOYEE.year = DELIVERY.year AND
EMPLOYEE.number = DELIVERY.number AND
EMPLOYEE.date = DELIVERY_DATE.date
```

To sum up, I'll end having EMPLOYEE joining both DELIVERY and DELIVERY_DATE, having the cycle in the join.
Should I rewrite it in this way?

```
EMPLOYEE.company = DELIVERY.company AND
EMPLOYEE.year = DELIVERY.year AND
EMPLOYEE.number = DELIVERY.number AND
EMPLOYEE.date IN (SELECT date FROM DELIVERY_DATE d WHERE d.delivery_id = DELIVERY.id)
```

***Edit 3: finally found a link***

As usual, when you've given up searching for a link, you find it.
So, **[this article](http://www.bidw.org/business-objects/universe-design/understanding-loops-and-its-resolution-technique-in-universe/)** explains all. It's related to Business Objects, but the content is generic.
Thanks to all for your time.

Comment: Hi, I edited the original question, sorry for not being clear...

Comment: Do you have a less abstract example scenario? There might be legitimate cases where you need to so something like that but trying to think when I would ever need such a design?

Comment: IMO there is nothing wrong with "loops". And I think that the example in the OP could even be a consequence of transposing a schema into 4NF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I see from the update that this is an issue that's specific to a BO designer, where a table is used more than once, but BO automatically combines join clauses, which then incorrectly (or, rather, unintentionally) restricts the result set.  This question actually has nothing to do with cycles, per se, it's really about using entities in more than one context in the same query.  I'll leave my original answer below, even though it doesn't really address OP's concern.

Disclaimer: This is a non-answer answer, because it's both an answer and a question.  It probably should be a comment, but you can't comment unless you ask/answer questions, but since I genuinely want to help, I'll do it the only way I can, even if it's not the way things are done here.  So sue me.

The short answer is no, you shouldn't avoid loops (or "cycles") in joins.

More to the point, queries are constructed so as to declare the correct logical condition(s) to produce the data you're looking for.  The same logical condition can often be established in many different ways, so sometimes it makes sense to ask if one way is preferable to another.  This becomes of particular interest when performance is important.  But first and foremost a query must return the right result set.  How this is accomplished depends on the underlying schema.  And this is what you really should be focused on.

In your example, why role does EMPLOYEE play regarding the DELIVERY tables?  Why would you join on those columns?  What would that mean that an EMPLOYEE has the same "date" as a delivery?  I understand it's a contrived example, but the point I'm trying to make is that whether joins create a cycle in the graph or not is wholly (well, principally) dependent on what a particular result set's logical *meaning* is.

And on the issue of JOIN syntax, using JOIN...ON clauses is preferable to WHERE clauses because it separates what you need to do to combine entities from data filtering operations.

Comment: The Employee table shows which employee worked on a delivery in a given date (ok, it's a bit contrived, I know).  
Thank you for the explaination.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your question is easy.  You should not be using `where` clauses to perform joins.  You should be using `on` clauses.  Your joins can be expressed as:

```
from Table1 join
     Table2
     on Table1.foo = Table2.foo join
     Table3
     on Table2.bar = Table3.bar and
        Table1.baz = Table3.baz
```

Whether this is appropriate or not depends on your data structures.  Sometimes it is.  You shouldn't worry about it.

By the way, I wouldn't refer to this as "loops" which is very associated with "for loops" in programming and nested loop joins in SQL.  You might refer to this as cycles in join conditions.

Wmax . . . as for the new join syntax.  It is not "just" a matter of taste.  The "," in a `from` clause *means* "cross join".  This is a very expensive operation, in most cases.  It is much better to be clear about what you want to accomplish:

```
FROM A cross join B
```

is much clearer about its intentions than:

```
FROM A, B
```

Second, if you leave the "," out, you still have valid syntax:

```
FROM A B
```

However, this means something very different (assigning the alias B to the table A).

The third reason is the most important reason.  The old syntax does not have a way of expressing `left outer join`, `right outer join`, and `full outer join`.

So, to write clearer queries, to avoid errors, and to access better functionality, you should learn the new syntax.

Comment: I would really like to hear why it is a bad thing to join tables using the where clause.. I've learned a while ago that its only a matter of taste.

Comment: @wmax: Both a person better versed in the older syntax and one more used to the newer one would probably have some hard time picking up each other's style of writing joins. But I would argue that the newer syntax is easier to adjust to. And it's even more likely to be easier to learn for a newbie. As it's already 20 years since the explicit join syntax has been introduced, there may already be quite a crowd of people much more accustomed to `FROM A JOIN B ON ...` than to `FROM A, B WHERE ...`. Of course, you can ignore all this if you are writing stuff for yourself (to read and maintain) only.

Comment: @wmax You are describing an "implicit join" when joining two tables with a WHERE clause. It is bad practice for the sake of readability- nothing more, since SQL optimizes its query the same way as with the JOIN syntax. HOWEVER, I recommend going the "textbook" way, just as somebody told me to do a long time ago.  It really does help in the long run, as you can see a mile away where the joins are on scripts that have multiple queries on the same page.

Comment: I agree with @wmax: it's just implicit vs. explicit notation.
I've added an example.